# Visual studio error while loading solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual studio 2015 and getting error while loading the solution.

```
 Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   devenv.exe
Problem Signature 02:   14.0.25420.1
Problem Signature 03:   57685d85
Problem Signature 04:   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition
Problem Signature 05:   14.3.11.26280
Problem Signature 06:   573fb65f
Problem Signature 07:   201
Problem Signature 08:   1d3
Problem Signature 09:   IOELOL5GVKXR2HCOZOJODXPHYNDFNEDB
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   5c97
Additional Information 2:   5c9732cff2a3c99c86a576145466de6f
Additional Information 3:   8a13
Additional Information 4:   8a134cd8a600f0d9955a5941a8d4fb95

Read our privacy statement online:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt'
```

I've used below commands:

```
1.devenv.exe /safemode
2.devenv.exe /resetskippkgs
3.devenv.exe /installvstemplates
4.devenv.exe /resetsettings
5.devenv.exe /resetuserdata
```

but it doesn'twork for me.

Comment: Seems you are running out of memory.  
Try to reduce the number of debug symbols loaded.
Alternatively try remove some unnecessary `*.pdb` files from your build

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently and it worked for me. I hope this can help you:

1. 1.- I repaired the .NET framework (in this case 4.6.1) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c4d9e707-19d1-460d-b620-262194c4f758/visual-studio-2013-professional-crashes-on-startup?forum=vssetup
2. Disabled Media Center Features https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/abcb54bb-5490-48ab-a961-f2c7f64331a3/visual-studio-startup-error-clr20r3?forum=vssetup
3. Executed:

   - devenv.exe /resetskippkgs
   - devenv.exe /resetsettings
   - devenv.exe/resetuserdata

As an extra comment: some people had issues with Git. And suggested to disable any git link of VS.